# Crear grupos en Azure Devops

Tags: azure, devops, vsts

Tengo una duda, estoy migrando una ApiRest a microservicios en AWS, pero los repos en la empresa se almacenan en AzureDevops.

Es posible crear un grupo en los repositorios de Azure para almacenar varios repositorios en Azure Devops como se puede hacer en gitlab?

Dado que ahora todos los servicios que estan en la Api se van a dividir.